# Double or More Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am working through some files that are within a folder hierarchy of Years>Months>Days (where days are the actual files I'm operating on).

Right now I am parallelizing at the day level, so doing eight files at once, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do some outer parallelization too over months and even years? Can I do something like:

```
pool = Pool()
pool.starmap(convertYears, years)
```

Then within convertYears function,

```
pool = Pool()
pool.starmap(convertMonths, months)
```

Then within convertMonths function,

```
pool = Pool()
pool.starmap(convertDays, files)
```

I don't know much about how the parallelization works, so that is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but `Pool` by default uses the maximum number of available processors, which means the maximum number of tasks that can be accomplished at once. That means if you have 8 processors available `convertYears` will open 8 at once, then each of those will open 8 (now to a total of 64) when they start `convertMonths` and each of those will will open 8 (now to a grand total of 512 processes) and all of those will come with the time and memory overhead of creating new processes, all while only 8 will be running anyway. Even if you use `Pool(2)` to limit each level, you still end up with 8 processes at once, which is exactly where you started.

Long story short, the program will be just as fast and your CPU won't hate you if you just stick to parallelizing at one level.

Comment: thanks, do you know if it's only possible to parallelize over processors or if it can be done over threads too? Please pardon anything I get wrong here, but it seems like I have 4 cores and 8 threads per core, so couldn't I have 32 processes being done? [This is my processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/97496/Intel-Core-i7-7820HQ-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz). os.cpu_count() only gives me the number 8, but I think there are some other methods in multiprocessing that give more. Am I on to something here?

Comment: Most likely, it's actually 4 cores, 2 logical processors per core, which is why cpu count gives you 8. Either way you slice it, that number is the maximum number of things your computer can do at once, processes, threads, or otherwise.

Comment: good to know. thank you! one last thing that is probably a can of worms: do you know about doing this kind of parallelization of a simple for loop over my gpu? I have an AMD Radeon Pro 560, so I think something like Tensorflow is out of the question since it only supports Nvidia, but perhaps there is a simple way of doing such a thing that you know about?

Comment: I am not personally familiar with moving tasks to the gpu.